# Calculate size of a circle from arcs?

Tags: svg, geometry, shapes, geometric-arc

How can I calculate the size of a circle from a set of arcs?

Specifically, I have this SVG path definition which draws a circle, I'm looking to work out its size.

```
<path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#99C44C" d="M334.293,56.846c0-4.782,3.88-8.659,8.665-8.659c4.78,0,8.66,3.877,8.66,8.659
    c0,4.783-3.88,8.661-8.66,8.661C338.173,65.507,334.293,61.629,334.293,56.846"/>
```

For your information, the circle is drawn in the 'd' attribute. M334.293,56.846 moves to this x,y position, then the c commands are curves.

Curves:

Draws a cubic Bézier curve from the current point to (x,y) using (x1,y1) as the control point at the beginning of the curve and (x2,y2) as the control point at the end of the curve. C (uppercase) indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; c (lowercase) indicates that relative coordinates will follow.

```
relative curves
c0-4.782,3.88-8.659,8.665-8.659
c4.78,0,8.66,3.877,8.66,8.659
c0,4.783-3.88,8.661-8.66,8.661

absolute curve
C338.173,65.507,334.293,61.629,334.293,56.846
```

Comment: That's not a circle. It's very close, but bezier curves can't accurately convey circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this juncture you have two possibilites:

You can treat the bezier curve as a circle (which is, as commented, wrong; it's just really circle-looking). To calculate the area, determine the radius and use `π * r^2` as usual.

If you want to calculate generally the area enclosed by a path element; that requires some moderate calculus, and is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the first option! Do you know how to determine the radius from the arcs?

Comment: @OllieG: When this "circle" is drawn; you move relatively towards positive x twice; both times moving 8.66 units. It's fairly clear from that that the radius is indeed 8.66 units. The movement on the Y axis corresponds to this; and is also consistently 8.66 units.